# HttpPostedFileBase Getting null when i use FileUpload control in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

This is my model class:

```
 public class FileUploadModel
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    }
```

This is My View:

```
@using VidesExample.Models
@model FileUploadModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FileUpload";
}

<h2>FileUpload</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload","Sample"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.File,new { type="file"})
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

And this is my Controller:

```
  public ActionResult FileUpload()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FileUpload(FileUploadModel obj)
        {
            var file=obj.File;
          //  if (video.File.ContentLength <= 0) return null;
          //  var fileName = Path.GetFileName(video.File.FileName);
          //  if (fileName == null) return null;
          //  var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Videos"), fileName);
          //  video.File.SaveAs(path);

          ////  return fileName;
         return View();
        }
```

When I try to getting the File it is displaying the null Value. and how to display and how to store the videos using Mvc.

Answer (score 1):

**Add** below **properties** in form tag

```
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActioName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```